# How these two inner class objects differ?

Tags: java, oop, inner-classes

I'm trying to delevope intuition and familiarity with inner classes.
I'm apporaching myslef to this java's topic and after some research I've started practicing.
I came up with this piece of code that behaves in a way that I can't understand.
I created a class **Example** with a public inner class **Inner**.
Inside the **Example** class I created an object of the **Inner** class **obj**, and in the class **MainClass**, inside the main function I created another **Inner** class instance ( After creating the instance of the enclosing class).
Example class code:

```
    public class Example {

    Inner obj = new Inner(9);

    class Inner {
        public int x;

        public Inner(int a) {
            x=a;
        }   
    }

}
```

Main class:

```
public class MainClass{
     public static void   main ( String args[] ) {

            Example example = new Example();
            System.out.println(example.obj.x); // output 9
            Example.Inner obj = example.new Inner(10);
            System.out.println(obj.x); //output 10
            System.out.println(example.obj.x); // output 9
            }
     }
```

Given that the statements `Inner obj= new Inner()` and the statement  `Example.Inner obj = example.new Inner(10)` both declare an object of the Inner class with the same name, I don't understand how this not give any problem. 
I think it's reltaed ot how they are loded in memory, but they seem to be 2 completley different things but I don't understand how.

**UPDATE:**
Answers have been great till now, I edited the question changing the code and  reducing the number of constructors to one. This should clarify what my doubts concern.

Comment: `obj` in `main` and `obj` in `Example` have no relation. Wouldn't we both be the same person if my name were Gabriele? Or just have an equal name without further relations?

Comment: Both variables have totally different scopes. One is a local variable of the main method. The other is a field of Example. Imagine if each loop `for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)` didn't compile because some other, unrelated code, also uses a variable named `i`. That would be unmanageable, wouldn't it?

Comment: Please downvote with explanation, at least I can try to edit! Votes are important to me, I made research for the question and I can be banned for 6 months just because someone was in a downvote mood!

Comment: How can this be a duplicate of the question above I don't even studied composition yet!?

Comment: To develop intuition and familiarity with inner classes, don't create them outside of their enclosing class. `Example.Inner obj = example.new Inner(10);` is not a typical usage. Use an inner class only if you need the access to the enclosing class's private fields and methods (not given in your example). And an inner class should be an implementation helper inside its enclosing class, not something you plan to use outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two instances of `Inner` class, although both instances have same name `obj`, they are separate from each other. `Inner` class instance defined outside `main` method is created using `default constructor`. So `example.obj.x` outputs `6`.

`Inner` class instance `obj` defined inside `main` method is created using `parameterized constructor` so `obj.x` outputs 10.

Important thing here is that when you do `example.obj.x`, you are referring to the instance of `Inner` class **created outside main method** and when you do `obj.x`, you are referring to the `Inner` class instance **created inside main method**. These two instances of `Inner` are completely separate from each other.

### EDIT

> Answers have been great till now, I edited the question changing the
>   code and reducing the number of constructors to one. This should
>   clarify what my doubts concern.

Having one or two constructors won't change anything. `Inner` class instance defined outside `main` method and the one defined inside `main` method are two separate instances of `Inner` class.

`x`, data member of instance of `Inner` defined outside `main` has value of `9` and can only be accessed using `Example` class's instance `example`. Hence `example.obj.x` outputs `9`.

Instance of `Inner` defined inside `main` is directly accessible using `obj` defined inside `main` and its `x` has a value of `10`.  Hence `obj.x` outputs `10`.

Comment: So the instance created in main method is not a field in the  outer class? Nor a sublcass , but it's just an instance, like the one of a non-inner class( defined in another file) that have acces to all members and methods of the outer and can be created only if an outer instance is created. Is that right? :)

Comment: @GabrieleScarlatti check the edited answer, hope it helps you better understand your code.

Comment: _So the instance created in main method is not a field in the outer class? Nor a sublcass , but it's just an instance. Is that right?_ Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Last thing: is this previous  thought correct too "ike the one of a non-inner class( defined in another file) that have acces to all members and methods of the outer and can be created only if an outer instance is created. Is that right? " I need to understand if I really get it!

Comment: Every instance of a class has access to its _public_ data members and _public_ methods and they can be accessed in another class using an instance of that class. _private_ methods or data members can only be accessed directly inside that class.

Answer (score 0):

You've created two objects: `example`, an instance of `Example`, and `obj`, an instance of `Example.Inner`. These two objects have nothing to do with each other, and share no information, so the `x` field in each can hold a different `int`.

Comment: I created an instance of Inner inside Example too, don't I?

Comment: Yes, you create an instance of `Inner` using the implicit constructor in `Example`, but the `obj` within `example` has nothing to do with the `obj` you manually created. They're different objects; you can create as many `Inner`s as you want, and put a different `int x` in each of them

Comment: Maybe things would be clearer if you use a different name for the object you create in the line `Example.Inner obj = example.new Inner(10);`. What if you said `Example.Inner myObj = example.new Inner(10);` instead? Then you wouldn't expect `myObj` and the `obj` that's within `example` to hold the same `int`, right? Just because the two things have the same name doesn't make them the same object.

Answer (score 0):

Irrespective of the fact that you have an inner class, you have two *completely* different instances of `Inner`.

`example.obj.x` is assigned the value of 6 due to the constructor for `Inner` assigning `6` to `x`.

`obj` is instantiating a new instance (hence the keyword `new`), and then it's passing in the value 10 for its constructor.

This is why you get two different values; because these two instances are completely separate from one another and have no shared values between each other (i.e. static field), the values will be different.